# How to pass self attributes to a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator for an object method:

```
def wrapper(func):
  def _wrapper(self, *a, **kw):
    print(self.foo)
    return func(self, *a, **kw)
  return _wrapper


class Bar:
  foo = 1
  
  @wrapper
  def baz(self):
    print(2)

# This works as expected :)
In [2]: Bar().baz()
1
2
```

I want to add another level of wrapping around this to allow parameters:

```
def wrapper(bla):
  def _wrapper(func):
    def __wrapper(self, *a, **kw):
      print(self.foo + bla)
      return func(self, *a, **kw)
    return __wrapper
  return _wrapper

class Bar:
  foo = 1

  @wrapper(1)
  def baz(self):
    print(2)

# which also works great
In [4]: Bar().baz()
2
2
```

Now, what I want to be able to do is pass a `self` attribute as a wrapper parameter, i.e. call it with something like this

```
class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    self._foo = 1

  @wrapper(self._foo)
  def baz(self):
    pass
```

I see 2 options:

1. make `self._foo` global
2. don't pass `self._foo`, and make the decorator access `self._foo`

Both are bad. (global can be changed from another place without my knowledge, and making the decorator access `self._...` means the decorator knows the class it operates on)
Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Pass the attribute name as a string and use `getattr()` in the decorator when the inner is called?

Comment: You can't do that. The decorator is called when the class is being _defined_, at which time there can't possibly be _any_ instances. The instance is only accessible inside your inner wrapper where it's a parameter. Could you give some more context as to the actual use case?

Comment: @IainShelvington is a technical solution, however, it suffers from the same problem my 2nd solution suffers

Comment: What _is_ that problem? You just say "both are bad".

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by _"the decorator knows the class it operates on"_, but Iain's suggestion of e.g. `@wrapper("_foo")` is only coupled insofar as that specific wrapper needs the `self` to have a `_foo` attribute - that's a coupling the actual _behaviour_ requires.

Comment: @CIsForCookies so your issue is with accessing the instance via the first/"self" parameter?

Comment: @IainShelvington My issue is that I don't want to have the decorator access `self`. I actually prefer to pass `self` as one of the `*a` parameters so this would be a generic decorator

Comment: @CIsForCookies To make it generic you could pass the index/name of the parameter you want to access and the name of the attribute? Something like `@wrapper(arg_index=0, attr='_foo')` and then in the decorator `getattr(args[arg_index])` or something like that?

Comment: @IainShelvington I could but that would complicate it too much for my taste. I think I better swallow my distaste for non generic decorators, and just go with it (i.e. with my 2nd option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works just fine (You can pick `_foo` or `_bar`) and the wrapper itself knows nothing of `Bar` nor its members:

```py
def wrapper(bla):
  def _wrapper(func):
    def __wrapper(self, *a, **kw):
      print(getattr(self, bla))
      return func(self, *a, **kw)
    return __wrapper
  return _wrapper

class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    self._foo = 1
    self._bar = 2

  @wrapper("_bar")  # pick _foo or _bar here
  def baz(self):
    pass


Bar().baz()
```

Output: `2`

The `wrapper` decorator can be located in another module, or as part of a library and `Bar` as the client will be unknown to the decorator.